# Find index of strings within a list that contain a specific character

Tags: python, indexing

I am very new to Python, but I have a problem that Google hasn't yet solved for me. I have a list of strings (f_list). I would like to generate a list of the indicies of the strings that contain a specific character ('>').

Example:
f_list = ['>EntryA', EntryB, '>EntryC', EntryD]

I would like to generate:
index_list = [0, 2]

This code works, but I have to enter the exact name of a string (ie. >EntryA) for Value. If I enter '>' (as indicated below in the code example), it returns no values in index_list.

```
    f_list = ['>EntryA', 'EntryB', '>EntryC', 'EntryD']
    index_list = []

    def all_indices(v, qlist):
        idx = -1
        while True:
            try:
                idx = qlist.find(v, idx+1)
                index_list.append(idx)
            except ValueError:
                break
        return index_list

    all_indices('>', f_list)
    print(index_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> [i for i, s in enumerate(f_list) if '>' in s]
[0, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter to find the strings:

```
>>> f_list = ['>EntryA', 'EntryB', '>EntryC', 'EntryD']
>>> filter(lambda s: '>' in s, f_list)
['>EntryA', '>EntryC']
```

Or use a list comprehension to find the indices:

```
>>> [i for i, s in enumerate(f_list) if '>' in s]
[0, 2]
```

Or you can find both with either:

```
>>> filter(lambda s: '>' in s[1], enumerate(f_list))
[(0, '>EntryA'), (2, '>EntryC')]

>>> [(i, s) for i, s in enumerate(f_list) if '>' in s]
[(0, '>EntryA'), (2, '>EntryC')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ever working with indexes, [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is your function:

```
>>> f_list = ['>EntryA', 'EntryB', '>EntryC', 'EntryD']
>>> for i, j in enumerate(f_list):
...     if '>' in j:
...         print i
... 
0
2
```

In a function:

```
>>> def all_indices(v, qlist):
...     return [i for i, j in enumerate(f_list) if '>' in j]
...
>>> all_indices('>', f_list)
[0, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is exactly what I needed and so much easier than what I was doing!